Stationary Solution to Hill's Equation of Motion
In Hill's problem for the three-body system, the dimensionless equations of motion can be written as follows:
$$
\frac{d^2\xi}{d\tau^{2}} - 2\frac{d\eta}{dt} = - \frac{\xi}{\rho^{3}} + 3\xi \, ,
\\
\frac{d^2\eta}{d\tau^{2}} + 2\frac{d\xi}{dt} = - \frac{\eta}{\rho^{3}} \, ,
\\
\frac{d^{2}\zeta}{d\tau^{2}} = - \frac{\zeta}{\rho^{3}} - \zeta \, ,
\\
\rho^{2} \equiv \xi^{2} + \eta^{2} + \zeta^{2} \, .
$$
To find the Lagrange points of Hill's equation, we assume stationary solutions, meaning
$d\xi/dt = d\eta/dt = d\zeta/dt = 0$. Under this assumption, the system of equations simplifies to:
$$
-\frac{\xi}{\rho^{3}} + 3\xi = 0 \, ,
\\
\eta= 0 \, ,
\\
- \frac{\zeta}{\rho^{3}} - \zeta = 0 \, .
$$
At this point, I can only derive the correct stationary solution if I assume $\zeta = 0$, but the equations themselves don't seem to explicitly suggest this assumption. Shouldn't it be possible to reach the final solution without making additional assumptions?
For reference, the final solution is:
$$
\xi = \pm 3^{-1/3} \, ,\eta = 0 \, , \zeta = 0 \, .
$$

Solving the system
$$
\cases{
\xi/\rho^3-3\xi=0\\ \eta/\rho^3=0\\ \zeta/\rho^3+\zeta=0\\ \rho^2=\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2
}
$$
we get at the real solutions
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho&\xi&\eta&\zeta\\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}& 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}} &  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
